# Burn and WiX - status quo and documentation

Tags: deployment, wix, wix3.5

What is the status of Burn in the [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) (Windows Installer XML) project? The blogs and websites don't say anything about it for the past couple of months...?

In the latest weekly release it is not included any more. As far as I understand it. And if it is still on the road, documentation would be really helpful. If there is any.

(I really like WiX and I'm using it a lot, but now I'm looking for a possibility to NOT include the complete .NET Framework as a prerequisite in the installation but download it on demand. And as far as I understood it, Burn would be the perfect tool to do this...)

Update (one year later): Newest blogpost for WiX 3.6 is *State of the WiX toolset, July 2011*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blog post *[Change of plans for WiX v3.5.](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/4/28/Change-of-plans-for-WiX-v3.5)* (2010-04-28) should answer your question. And this blog is the **original source**. :-)

Comment: Hi Yan, thanks for this Link. Now it is all clear...

Nice greetings from germany,
Markus

Answer (score 3):

WiX 3.6 has now [been released](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2012/9/3/WiX-v3.6-released) and is the first WiX release to include Burn.

Documentation is still a little sparse, however the following links should get you started

- [Building Installation Package Bundles](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_intro.htm) (official documentation)
- [WiX Burn – tips/tricks](http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/wix-burn-tipstricks.html)
- [Burn UI Customisations](http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/burn-ui-customisations.html)
- [Introducing Managed Bootstrapper Applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2011/10/28/introducing-managed-bootstrapper-applications.aspx)